# Laravel htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to get list of language which provided by `languages.php` in my config folder and I get this error

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\laragon\www\newproject\resources\views\layouts\panel.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\newproject\resources\views\layouts\panel.blade.php)
```

Here is my `languages.php`

```
<?php

return [
  'en' => [
      'name' => 'English',
      'flag' => 'images/flags/en.png'
  ],
  'fa' => [
      'name' => 'پارسی',
      'flag' => 'images/flags/iran.png'
  ],

];
```

My middleware `Language.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class Language
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (Session::has('applocale') AND array_key_exists(Session::get('applocale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
          App::setLocale(Session::get('applocale'));
      }
      else { // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
          App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

`LanguageController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function index($lang)
    {
      if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
            Session::put('applocale', $lang);
        }
        return Redirect::back();
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', ['as'=>'lang.switch', 'uses'=>'LanguageController@index']);
```

and finally my view

```
<li class="dropdown langs">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
  {{ Config::get('languages') }} <span class="caret"></span>
</a>

 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   @foreach (Config::get('languages') as $lang => $language)
   @if ($lang != App::getLocale())
   <li>
     <a href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}">{{ $language['name'] }}</a>
   </li>
   @endif
   @endforeach
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: issue is in 'layouts\panel.blade.php' , please share this file.

Comment: @sunitiyadav I did the last part code in my question is my panel.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line `{{ Config::get('languages') }}` on the dropdown definition, here you wish to print a string instead you are trying to print the full array taken from **languages.php** like a string hence the **htmlspecialchars** function fails because the first argument mismatch the required argument type.

Comment: Ok, i get it but i need to show selected language in top, how do i do that?

Comment: @mafortis {{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()]['name'] }} will be a choice, your app always has a locale and you can accss the config languages using the locale as a key.