# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in laravel blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, matrix

I am performing an audit, comparing between old_values ​​and new_values ​​fields. **All the modifications made are stored in the columns (old_values ​​and new_values), in TEXT format.** **I have a problem wanting to show the fields that have been modified and correspond to the new_values ​​column of my audit table.** This is how I loop through the old_values ​​column without any problem:

```
<td>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
        @foreach($audit->old_values as $attribute => $value)         
          <tr>
             <td><b>{{ $attribute  }}</b></td>                                         
             <td>{{  $value }}</td>                                                                      
          </tr>                                  
         @endforeach
     </table>
</td>
```

So I apply the same to the new_values ​​column and can't access the modifications:

```
<td>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
        @foreach($audit->new_values as $attributee => $value)         
          <tr>
             <td><b>{{ $attributee }}</b></td>                                         
             <td>{{  $value }}</td>                                                                      
          </tr>                                  
         @endforeach
     </table>
</td>
```

This is the error:

> **htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

So I tried the following: 1) inspect with dd ($ audit-> new_values) 
Outcome:

```
array:4 [▼
  "category_id" => "2"
  "title" => "Mi cuarto post edit"
  "excerpt" => "Extracto de mi cuarto post edit"
  "body" => "<p>Contenido de mi cuarto post edit</p>"
]
```

2) Then probe with array_get Outcome:

```
  <td>{{ array_get($value, 'value.category_id'. default) }} </td>
```

[image: new_values]

This is my audit table: I want to show the data of the row that is highlighted in red (new_values):

[image: tabla audit]

**Can someone help me solve this problem? How do I correctly cycle through my array?**

**UPDATED 1**

Perform a new test by creating a new post, then edit the same post to compare the old_values ​​and new_values ​​fields.
Inspecting I receive this error on line 62

[image: value2]

Comment: @Helioarch inspect with dd($audit-> new_values ​​()) ```array:4 [▼
  "category_id" => "2"
  "title" => "Mi cuarto post edit"
  "excerpt" => "Extracto de mi cuarto post edit"
  "body" => "<p>Contenido de mi cuarto post edit</p>"
]```

Comment: Maybe another kind of same error message : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210547/laravel-htmlspecialchars-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given?rq=1

Comment: where are you `dd()`ing ? i was asking for a var dump/dd in the blade because i was trying to make sure that no other code was modifying `$audit->new_values` before the loop..

Comment: @Helioarch I am having trouble executing {{var_dump ($ audit-> new_values)}}, it just throws the same error for me, I am testing it before it goes through the loop, any suggestions?

Comment: oh i'm sorry i made the wrong suggestion.. can you instead do a `@dd($audit->new_values)` or `@php(dd($audit->new_values))` right before the loop in your blade

Comment: @Helioarch That is the result verifying with ```@dd($audit->new_values)``` 
```array:3 [▼
  "title" => "mi sexto post editado"
  "excerpt" => "extracto sexto post editado"
  "body" => "<p>sexto post editado</p>"
]```

Comment: @Helioarch I have just tried showing my two variables in a ```<td>{{ $attribute2[$value2] }}</td>``` and I get the following error: **Illegal string offset 'mi sexto post editado'**
I just want to show: 'my sixth edited post', I really don't understand

Comment: @Helioarch Please check my update 1, create a new post save it then edit it to see its modifications, I think the error is on the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment and edits, it seems like you have a value that is in the form of an array so you could try to print it as string using `{{ is_array($value2) ? json_encode($value2) : $value2 }}`

Comment: Thanks I have been dealing with this for a long time, you can solve it with the indicated.
The problem was in a publish_at field in which I store the date.
The date is important to me, how can I show only the date? In publish_at I get all this ```{"date":"2020-04-08 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America\/Argentina\/Buenos_Aires"}``` and just want the date.
How can I show the date?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz You would have to show an example of the data in your publish_at field and your expected result. But please post it as another question to keep it clean.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, and to evict any naming problem while naming variables, I use other names to loop inside any collections or doing some stuff.
Did you try too loop with :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
    @foreach($audit->new_values as $attribute2 => $value2)         
      <tr>
         <td><b>{{ $attribute2 }}</b></td>                                         
         <td>{{ $value2 }}</td>                                                                      
      </tr>                                  
     @endforeach
 </table>
```

Comment: I followed his recommendation to change the names of the variables as I indicate, but I receive the same error, I ask him a question because if I use array_get it does not throw any error, but in this case it is not bringing me the values, look at my first image